# в 1С 8.3 как определить значения списка выбора из табличной части справочника?

Tags: 1с

Вопрос по 1С 8.3, управляемые формы.
Дано 2 справочника. 
Один - с табличной частью в форме элемента.
Второй, подчиненный первому - с полем ввода типа Список значений, в котором должно быть можно выбирать значения из одной из колонок табличной части первого справочника.

Я решил взять табличную часть, вычленить из неё данные одной колонки в массив и передать его в список значений. Получилось что-то такое:

```
&НаСервереБезКонтекста
Функция Реквизит1НачалоВыбораНаСервере(Владелец)

    ТЗ = Владелец.БлокСекцииТабло.Выгрузить();  
    Массив = ТЗ.ВыгрузитьКолонку("БлокСекция");
    Возврат Массив;

КонецФункции
&НаКлиенте
Процедура Реквизит1НачалоВыбора(Элемент, ДанныеВыбора, СтандартнаяОбработка)
    Владелец = ЭтаФорма.Объект.Владелец.Ссылка;
    Массив = Реквизит1НачалоВыбораНаСервере(Владелец);  
    Элементы.Реквизит1.СписокВыбора.Очистить();
    Элементы.Реквизит1.СписокВыбора.ЗагрузитьЗначения(Массив);

КонецПроцедуры
```

В результате данные берутся, при нажатии на выбор из выпадающего списка в нем появляются нужные мне значения. Но при выборе любого из них поле по-прежнему остается пустым.

Где я мог ошибиться, и что можно еще добавить/убрать для решения проблемы?

Comment: Тип реквизита табличной части какой? Возможно он отличается от типа элемента выбора.